# How to specify a database connection to Doctrine fixtures?

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine, continuous-integration

I am using **Symfony 4** and I have a *CI pipeline* to deploy my app to a dev server. Using **Doctrine** features, I can execute the database migrations using a `--db-configuration` option:

```sh
./bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate \
    --allow-no-migration \
    --db-configuration=dev_conn.php \
    --no-interaction
```

I would like to load the fixtures in the same manner, but the `--db-configuration` option isn't listed in help for the `doctrine:fixtures:load` command.

- Is there an *"hidden"* option to this command which could do this ?
- If not, what would be the best workaround to be able to load fixtures on my remote server ?

Comment: What about create a Entity manager with credentials of the remote server https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html and pass the option —em=your_second_manager

Comment: Thanks @Smaine, I should give it a try, I just hope it'll accept that both default and dev em manage the same entities

Comment: Hi @Smaïne, it works. Would you like to post the solution as an answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create another **Entity Manager** with credentials of the remote server (using another environment variable) as described [in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) and pass the option`—em=your_second_manager` in your fixtures command.

Answer (score 0):

you can define a symfony service for each of your entitymanagers and inject the desired one explicitly into your fixture class afterwards. the fixture would then be a service as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to keep the same fixtures for local environment and the development servers. All I need to change is the database connection during deployment. If I misunderstood your answer you can edit your answer to provide a quick example