# MYSQL times out after executing fixtures load

Tags: php, mysql, docker, doctrine, fixtures

I am running MySQL on a Docker container and I am connected to my database (I,ve added items via postman so I know it’s connected).  However, I tried to add doctrine fixtures and then load them but it times out.   Anybody ran into this issue before?

```
class AppFixtures extends Fixture
{
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $blogPost = new BlogPost();
    $blogPost->setTitle('A First post!');
    $blogPost->setPublished(new DateTime('2019-07-01 12:00:00'));
    $blogPost->setContent('Post Text!');
    $blogPost->setAuthor('Chris Moreno');
    $blogPost->setSlug('a-first-post');

    $manager->persist($blogPost);

    $blogPost = new BlogPost();
    $blogPost->setTitle('A Second post!');
    $blogPost->setPublished(new DateTime('2019-07-01 12:00:00'));
    $blogPost->setContent('Post Text!');
    $blogPost->setAuthor('Chris Moreno');
    $blogPost->setSlug('a-second-post');

    $manager->persist($blogPost);

    $manager->flush();
  }
}
```

error when calling this:

```
php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

error msg:

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:

An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you properly specified database connection details in Doctrine fixtures?

Check [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) out and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56419241/how-to-specify-a-database-connection-to-doctrine-fixtures).

Comment: I think this would work if I had two databases but I only have one along with one connection through a docker container.  not sure how about going and connecting differently to the same docker container for doctrine fixtures, any idea?